# spring model is sometimes empty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model

i am confused about availibility from data within spring-model.
Example:

```
@RequestMapping("myAbosolutPathAAA.action")
    public String myHandlerONE(@RequestParam(required = false) String date, Model model){
     ArryList<Car> myCars = carsDAO.findAll(); //retrieve all cars from DB.
    model.addAttribute(CARS, myCars);
return "page1.action";
}
```

Now i can handle my car-list on frontend.
At next i navigate on next controler-handler, where i need myCars-list again.
So i dont want to retrieve database anymore. I want to retrieve my spring-model:

```
@RequestMapping("myAbosolutPathBBB.action")
    public String myHandlerTWO(@RequestParam String name, Model model){
     ArryList<Car> myCars = model.asMap().get(CARS); //retrieve spring-model and not db .
    //do somethings with car list....
    return "page2.action";
}
```

But when i want to retrieve spring-model, my car-list is null.
Sometimes it works. I can not finde any explanation on spring-reference.
Can's anybody explain, when can i retrieve spring-model and when not?

Comment: The model is only valid and available for the current request. It isn't shared between requests. If you want to keep stuff you need to use `@SessionAttributes` else the elements are removed from the model after the request finishes. However instead of doing that I would strongly suggest to just retrieve it and add it to the model again and use some caching mechanism instead.

Comment: When it is available only on current request, how can you retrieve model basicaly?
I suppose, that request ends, when handler-function executes last code line. It means, that i can never retrieve spring model, cause each request i start, is new.

Comment: The current request ends when your page finished rendering (or whatever your response is).